# Include a range of data using offset in email

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

I have a list of products in a worksheet which are highlighted different colours to show product groups. Each highlighted colour has a corresponding number (grey = 15, yellow = 19, etc.).

I am trying to include the range of cells 1, 2 & 3 places to the right of the colour code into body text of email. I'm not bothered about retaining any borders or colour once its in the email as I'm even less sure about HTML stuff.

I left redundant code so I can identify what I was attempting to achieve.
There are multiple sections of code above this that save as pdf, send email, etc.

```vb
'===========================
'EMAIL PLACE MATERIAL ORDER'
'===========================

'shamelessly stolen from https://www.exceldemy.com/macro-to-send-email-from-excel/

     Dim Cell As Range                               '¦
     Dim ws As Worksheet                             '¦
     Set eApp = New Outlook.Application              '¦ <- no touchy
     Set eItem = eApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)         '¦
     eItem.To = "email@email.com" '<- email address of recipient

'These items are optional
'eItem.CC = "x@gmail.com"
'etem.BCC = "y@gmail.com"

'Email subject, currently as cell info
     eItem.Subject = Range("D21").Value

'Email body text
     eItem.Body = "Automated Email - advise sender of errors." _
     & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
     "Please order the following:" _
     & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
     vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
     "ws.cells(1, 2).value on the ws.cells(73, 13).value" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
     ws.Range("h73:i100") 'i know this last line is total twaddle

'If you want to attach this workbook, then uncomment these two lines from below
'Source = This`your text`Workbook.FullName
'eItem.Attachments.Add Source
     eItem.Display 'can use .Send

    'Range("B2").Interior.ColorIndex
    '=SUMIF(Table4[Column1],15,F24:F29)
```

[image]

Comment: Please update the screenshot to include row and column headings.

Comment: that would have been helpful! added revised screenshot - thank you for the bump

Comment: `include the range of cells 1,2&3 places to the right of the colour code` Does it mean all items which is colored as 1, 2 and 3?

Comment: not certain how well i managed that - i was told i couldnt add images without 10 rep; i think its added the image as a link at the bottom

Answer (score 1):

`Body` is a plain text property which *doesn't* deliver any formatting.

```
eItem.Body = "Automated Email - advise sender of errors." _
```

Instead, I'd suggest using the Word object model for copying and pasting the Excel data directly to the message body. See [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012(v=office.12).aspx) for more information.

Also you may consider using the `HTMLBody` property instead. For example, you can find the following function which builds an HTML string based on the Excel range passed as a parameter:

```
Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook
 
    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "/" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"
 
    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With
 
    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With
 
    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.ReadAll
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")
 
    'Close TempWB
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False
 
    'Delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill TempFile
 
    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

- Loop through all rows to extract the data.
- The data in a row is seperated by <kbd>TAB</kbd>.

```vb
    'Email body text
    Dim oSht As Worksheet, sTxt As String
    Dim lastRow As Long, sItem As String, arrData
    Const COLOR_CODE = "|1|2|3|"
    Set oSht = Sheets("Sheet1") ' modify sheet name as needed
    lastRow = oSht.Cells(oSht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    If lastRow > 23 Then
        arrData = oSht.Range("B24:C24")
        For i = LBound(arrData) To UBound(arrData)
            If InStr(1, COLOR_CODE, "|" & arrData(i, 5) & "|", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                ' Cocate Col B, C, E
                sTxt = arrData(i, 1) & vbTab & arrData(i, 2) & vbTab & arrData(i, 4)
                If Len(sItem) = 0 Then
                    sItem = sTxt
                Else
                    sItem = sItem & vbNewLine & sTxt
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End If
    eItem.Body = "Automated Email - advise sender of errors." & _
        vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Please order the following:" & _
        vbNewLine & vbNewLine & sItem & vbNewLine
```